# How to call an Azure Rest API from an Azure Web Application

Tags: azure, rest, asp.net-web-api, service-principal

I was wondering if I can get some direction on this problem. I have an Azure Rest API that I only want a few of my Azure Web Apps access to. I thought if I deny anonymous on the Rest API and set up the Web Apps' service principals in AAD I would be able to achieve this. Most of the examples I seen require the user of the Web App to login which is not a requirement for what I am doing. Essentially the Web Apps are the only consumers and I know their Service Principal information but I can't figure the next step.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `Managed Service Identity`. Essentially you would assign an identity to your WebApps and then only allow access to the API from these identities.

You can find more information about Managed Service Identity here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet.